# why can we say "faster than necessary" but not "closer than safe"

Tags: comparative-constructions

> These crazy motorists were driving faster than necessary. <sup>grammatical</sup>
>
> And these a-holes were tailgating, getting much closer than safe, risking our lives. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Why is "closer than safe" ungrammatical and yet "faster than necessary" is OK?

Comment: Maybe 'necessary' can stand for a full clause, as in *If necessary, you can contact me at home.*, where "if necessary" = "if it's necessary". That's just my conjecture though. :)

Comment: Could be. I think it has to do with an embedded passive in **necessary**, i.e *needed (to be)*.

Comment: I wouldn't say that *closer than safe* is ungrammatical. It has exactly the same construction as *faster than necessary* and is just as understandable. Both have an elided *was*. It's simply that the one is less common, so it sounds a bit strange.

Comment: Can we say "He drove faster than prudent"? I don't think so. Strikes my ear as something other than unusual.  *He divulged more than safe*.   ??

Comment: Interesting question, probably more appropriate on ELU or Linguistics sites.

Comment: Close, but more natural would be "getting much closer than (is/would be) safe, risking our lives." But I don't think the phrases in your examples are valid for comparison purposes. The second one involves risk possibility, the first one is a statement of fact. You should explain further what you are thinking.

Comment: @user3169:  We agree that the second, "closer than safe", is not grammatical, *pace* Jason, who thinks it is fine, if "less common". What I want to know is, what is different about "faster than necessary" and "closer than safe" that makes the former grammatical and the latter not.  I don't think the difference can be explained by a "fact vs. risk" opposition.

Comment: Maybe it is a matter of what is commonly omitted. Because "faster than (is) necessary." would be equivalent to "closer than (is) safe". Actually, "risking their lives" could be added to both, so maybe that's not relevant.

Comment: What source did you use to label these sentences grammatical or ungrammatical? Answering the question seems to assume you have high confidence in the labeling.

Comment: @RuslanD: I am a native speaker.   I do not believe their ungrammaticality is limited to my particular dialect of American English (Central Atlantic)

Comment: I am a native speaker, and they all seem grammatical to me. Some of them do sound a bit awkward as the omitted word is not immediately obvious on hearing them, but I do not see how or why that would render them ungrammatical.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz:You find *He divulged more than safe* grammatical?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes. The "is" or "was" can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is 'than'; we must compare like-for-like.

'Safe' is a simple adjective which must apply to a noun, gerund or equivalent clause. 'Safe' by itself can thus only be compared literally with another adjective, e.g. 'My work was more dangerous than safe'.

'Necessary' is indeed a complex, multi-role word, which can be used (as in the example) as a noun-clause to mean eg 'a certain speed'; as in 'driving faster than [a certain speed]'. It can also work as an adjective.

To answer the question: if you want to use 'than safe' you can:

(a) provide a noun for 'safe' to describe: eg 'Driving closer than a safe distance';

(b) provide an adjective to compare 'safe' with: eg 'driving at a distance more dangerous than safe'.

(c) In practice, inserting the strong verb 'was' is simplest, because it emphasises that its subject has been left out, and must be re-imagined: eg 'driving closer than (a distance that) was safe'.

In the comment above, 'He divulged more than safe' sounds wrong because you can't literally compare the adjective 'safe' with the 'info' that was divulged. Again, inserting 'was' forces the re-imagination of what was divulged:
'He divulged more (info than the amount that) was safe.'

CAUTION: In general, elision or dropping of words is a poet's tactic which can decorate language, and it helps create easily-learned, short expressions, which naturally find their way into the patois or argot often learned first by non-native speakers. However, in technical and legal work,  words should not be dropped except when necessary, because it is not safe to assume that the reader will imagine the same word as you have just left out.